# Game Specification Posts

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I was thinking it might be useful to have a question that would read something like:

> What is Advanced Squad Leader?

Maybe asking as a CW question, then have a CW answer that people can edit to list out the details of the game.  This would eventually give us an in-site place to link to instead of BGG (though you might have a BGG link in that answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a game is important enough to merit its own tag, *that* would seem the logical place to have a full write-up on the game. If you look at the [tags page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags) you can already find:

- [dominion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion)
- [settlers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settlers-of-catan)
- [battlestar-galatica](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galatica)
- [carcassonne](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carcassonne)
- [chess](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)
- [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering)
- And so on.

If a game is missing from the tags, ask a question about the game. Then edit the tag-wiki.

Comment: Good Idea......

Comment: Exactly - this is what I tried to do with [Arkham Horror](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/arkham-horror/info), for example.